# mapping JSON for dynamic parameters to POJO

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, gson

I have a `JSON` like this that have dynamic object

```
{
 "related": {
  "0": {
    "post_id": "4869",
    "likes_count": "0",
    "product_id": "5348",
    "stock_current": "10000",
    "selling_price": "17500000.00"
  },
  "1": {
    "post_id": "4870",
    "likes_count": "0",
    "product_id": "5348",
    "stock_current": "10000",
    "selling_price": "10500000.00"
  },
  "2": {
    "post_id": "4871",
    "likes_count": "0",
    "product_id": "5348",
    "stock_current": "10000",
    "selling_price": "15500000.00"
  },
  "related_total": "33"
 }
}
```

How to map it to `POJO`, if the parameter is dynamic except the `"related_total"`, and can be more than 3 object?

Usually when I have a json like this

```
{
 "related": {
  "0": {
    "post_id": "4869",
    "likes_count": "0",
    "product_id": "5348",
    "stock_current": "10000",
    "selling_price": "17500000.00"
  },
  "1": {
    "post_id": "4870",
    "likes_count": "0",
    "product_id": "5348",
    "stock_current": "10000",
    "selling_price": "10500000.00"
  },
  "2": {
    "post_id": "4871",
    "likes_count": "0",
    "product_id": "5348",
    "stock_current": "10000",
    "selling_price": "15500000.00"
  }
 }
}
```

My Pojo will be like this

```
public class PojoExample {


@SerializedName("related")
@Expose
private Map<String,Related> related;


public Map<String,Related> getRelated() {
    return related;
}


public void setRelated(Map<String,Related> related) {
    this.related = related;
}


public class Related {

    @SerializedName("post_id")
    @Expose
    private String postId;
    @SerializedName("likes_count")
    @Expose
    private String likesCount;
    @SerializedName("product_id")
    @Expose
    private String productId;
    @SerializedName("stock_current")
    @Expose
    private String stockCurrent;
    @SerializedName("selling_price")
    @Expose
    private String sellingPrice;

   // getter and setter here

 }
}
```

I use the `POJO`for retrofit

Comment: have you tried running your code with the POJO class posted above?

Comment: why don't you change the structure and make your life easier?

Comment: {"related": [{
    "post_id": "4869","likes_count": "0","product_id": "5348","stock_current":"10000","selling_price": "17500000.00"
  },{},...], "related_total": "33"}......'related' would be a list of dynamic objects

Comment: just change `Map<String,Related>` to `List<Map<String,Related>>`